# Jump to element's position on the page from the Chrome DevTools element inspector?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a very large page. Im finding elements by searching for their class name in the elements section of the DevTools. I then need to find element ive selected in the inspector on the page, but the size of the page makes this difficult.

Is there a way once you've selected an element in the inspector of jumping to its location on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on the element text, click "Scroll into View".

Comment: This menu item does not seem to appear for local pages (HTML pages stored on my hard disk, that I open with Chromium). Any idea why and how to enable it for those? Or can it possibly due to the absence of Javascript on that page?

Answer (score 3):

Daniel's answer is probably the most straightforward approach and one that I would use if performing this task once in a while, but with a little Javascript prowess we can execute this in the console, because why not?

In the Console window of Chrome Dev Tools enter the following and press `ENTER`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
```

Explanation:

`document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName')` retrieves all elements that have the class name you are looking for.

The `[0]` is the index you'll use to access the items in the collection of elements that were retrieved. Because this is a zero-based array, `[0]` gets you the first instance of the class name you're looking for.

Finally, `scrollIntoView(true)` does exactly what it says, surprisingly, by scrolling the element, which in this case is the first element that has the class name of "ClassName", into view. The `true` argument that is passed in tells the method to align the element with the top of the window. `false` would align it to the bottom.

So if you find yourself repeating this task for a large page, as you say you are, you could execute this function once, press `UP` on the console window, change the index, rinse wash and repeat. Like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName')[0].scrollIntoView(true); //First item
document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName')[1].scrollIntoView(true); //Second item
document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName')[2].scrollIntoView(false); //Third item, aligned to the bottom of the screen
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick that includes the previous posters answer:

If you work with the console, and query elements from the command line, `$[0]` will pull up the last queried element.  You can the right click on it and choose `reveal in elements panel`, and then finish by scrolling into view.

It provides gobs of sanity on large pages.